# Read Socket in PHP, receive only Trash

Tags: php, sockets

i try to read gps data from my Teltonika router. I can receive data, but that are only trash for my eyes. So i cant parse that. 
That are my received data: (the red is my IMEI Number...)
[image]

And that is my PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'FMXXXX_Parser/Parser.class.php';

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n"); }

echo "Socket created \n";

if( !socket_bind($sock, '10.81.0.1' , 62250) ) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n"); }

echo "Socket bind OK \n";
$remote_ip = '10.81.0.1';
$remote_port = 62250;
while(1) {
    echo "Waiting for data ... \n";
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 4096, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;
    die;
}
socket_close($sock);
```

Have somebody an idea?

Comment: In what format is the data supposed to be?

Comment: Looks like you've got the data, now you need to use the Parser that you've included to decode the data. See https://github.com/barryib/FMXXXX_Parser/blob/master/test.php for an example.

Comment: I have parts of the Code from this site you have linked, and i use the test.php, but my parsed data is trash too. So i think my problem beginns before parse the data. Look here about the supposed data: https://wiki.teltonika.lt/index.php?title=RUT955_Protocols